# Airflow Get Retry Number

Tags: airflow

In my Airflow DAG I have a task that needs to know if it's the first time it's ran or if it's a retry run. I need to adjust my logic in the task if it's a retry attempt.

I have a few ideas on how I could store the number of retries for the task but I'm not sure if any of them are legitimate or if there's an easier built in way to get this information within the task.

- I'm wondering if I can just have an integer variable inside the dag that I append every time the task runs. Then if the task if reran I could check the value of the variable to see that it's greater than 1 and hence would be a retry run. But I'm not sure if mutable global variables work that way in Airflow since there can be multiple workers for different tasks (I'm not sure on this though).
- Write it in an XCOM variable?

Answer (score 20):

The retry number is available from the task instance, which is available via the macro `{{ task_instance }}`. https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables

If you are using the python operator simply add `provide_context=True,` to your operator kwargs, and then in the callable do `kwargs['task_instance'].try_number`

Otherwise you can do something like:

```
t = BashOperator(
    task_id='try_number_test',
    bash_command='echo "{{ task_instance.try_number }}"',
    dag=dag)
```

Edit:

When the task instance is cleared, it will set the max_retry number to be the current try_number + retry value. So you could do something like:

```
ti = # whatever method you do to get the task_instance object
is_first = ti.max_tries - ti.task.retries + 1 == ti.try_number
```

Airflow will increments the try_number by 1 when running, so I imagine you'd need the + 1 when subtracting the max_tries from the configured retry value.  But I didn't test that to confirm

Comment: This is a good feature thanks. I did a simple test with the BashOperator shown here and when I go to rerun the DAG by clearing all the past, future, ..., upstream, etc. that the next time it runs it still knows about the previous runs. So if I run it twice the second run it'll say the try_number is 2. I feel like it should clear the try_number when you clear the task runs..

Comment: Updated my answer.  Airflow will always increment the try_number when it runs a task.  This is important so you always know how many times the code has been run.  To compensate, it increases the max_retries by the configured retry amount from the current try_number.  So you should be able to work backwards from there to determine the if it's the first run in the current state

Comment: the link in your post is a 404

Comment: Sorry this question is ~3 years old, Looks like their docs have been updated. I wasn't able to quickly find a newer doc, but it shouldn't be directly necessary anyway in context of the question

Answer (score 6):

@cwurtz answer was spot on. I was able to use it like this:

```py
    def _get_actual_try_number(self, context):
        '''
        Returns the real try_number that you also see in task details or logs.
        '''
        return context['task_instance'].try_number

    def _get_relative_try_number(self, context):
        '''
        When a task is cleared, the try_numbers continue to increment.
        This returns the try number relative to the last clearing.
        '''
        ti = context['task_instance']
        actual_try_number = self._get_actual_try_number(context)

        # When the task instance is cleared, it will set the max_retry
        # number to be the current try_number + retry value.
        # From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757521
        relative_first_try = ti.max_tries - ti.task.retries + 1

        return actual_try_number - relative_first_try + 1
```