# Persisting state on airflow sensor rescheduled runs

Tags: airflow

I am working with `BaseSensorOperator` in Airflow. I have a use-case in which I'd like the `BaseSensorOperator.poke(context)` function to pass some information to the next call of `poke`. I have attempted using Xcom as follows (mock case with meaningless values passed):

```py
    def poke(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']
        old_value = task_instance.xcom_pull(key='passing_this_value')
        if old_value:
            logging.info(f'retrieved from Xcom {old_value}')
        else:
            logging.info('no value was retrieved')
        new_value = datetime.now()
        logging.info(f'sending this value to Xcom {new_value}')
        task_instance.xcom_push(key='passing_this_value', value=new_value)

        if new_value.minute % 10 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This works great when the sensor task is created with `method='poke'` but fails when `method='reschedule'` because on rescheduling Xcom is cleared for the task in that run.

Is there a way around it? I could use `Variable` but that would greatly litter the variable space. Any other suggestion?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757521/3679900), the [`{{ task_instance }}` macro](https://airflow.apache.org/macros.html#default-variables) maybe helpful. Check source [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L201)

Comment: @y2k-shubham, you mean to create an `airflow.models.variable` with a unique name? such as `'{{task_instance.dag_id}}_{{task_instance.task_id}}_{{task_instance.execution_date}}'` I considered this option. In this case, would there be a way to clear the variable at the end of the task execution (success or failure)?

Comment: @y2k-shubham, Sorry, i think I misunderstood you. Indeed I could use `context['task_instance'].try_number()` instead of my more cumbersome solution. What I am looking for , though, is a way to have my new method `self.trigger(context)` communicate with the poke method.

Comment: **@Giovanni**, I didn't quite understand `.."to have my new method self.trigger(context) communicate with the poke method.."`. Could you please elaborate it (perhaps edit the question itself)?

Comment: @y2k-shubham, I will do this first thing tomorrow. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @y2k-shubham, I have edited my question. Hope that now my problem is more clear. Again thanks.

Comment: You already know that you can use any external system to persist state / transmit messages across calls of `poke()` function (including `Airflow` `Variable` / `XCOM`, both of which are persisted in Airflow's meta-db). I think as long as [`mode=poke`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py#L47), you might be able to simply persist state / message in a simple **`python` global-variable** within your `CustomSensor` class. But with `mode=reschedule`, I can't think of an easy way to pull this off

Comment: beware that with `try_number` there could be [gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57886226/3679900) *[i've never tested it, just adding link for reference]*

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem as you. With the "reschedule" mode, it cleans every property of the task instance, including the xcom.

In fact, every xcom message is identified with the DAG_ID, TASK_ID, EXECUTION_DATE and the KEY.

In order to not let the reschedule mechanism to clean up the xcom for the task instance, I find a way to do it by using the XCOM interface directly instead of the one of TI. But, we need to modify the TASK_ID to another one in order to espace the clean up process.

Here is my code :

```
    def poke(self, context):
    request_id = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key="requestId", task_ids=self.task_id + "_original", dag_id=self.dag_id)
    if request_id is None:
        self.log.info("requestId not found, so we launch the Lambda function")
        request_id = self.launch_lambda()

        # To avoid task reschedule clean the xcom message, we use the XCom API directly to push the requestId
        # but with a taskId modified
        XCom.set(
            key="requestId",
            value=request_id,
            task_id=self.task_id + "_original",
            dag_id=self.dag_id,
            execution_date=context['ti'].execution_date)
        self.log.info("Pushed requestId %s to xcom", request_id)
```

Comment: Wonderful, work like a charm, thank you !