# AIrflow - task_instance.try_number is not working

Tags: airflow

I am trying to send parameter to an airflow task in order to identify the last execution.

The following code **always** send {"try_number": "1"} as POST data.

Airflow version: 1.10.2

Thanks

```
    xxx = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='XXX',
        endpoint='/backend/XXX',
        http_conn_id='backend_url',
        data=json.dumps({"try_number": "{{ti.try_number}}"}),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        response_check=lambda response: response.json().get('status') == 'ok',
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the rendered view,
I looked at the rendered result's instead of viewing the actual value of the operator.

I pushed the output to new XCOM (xcom_push=True) and now I can see the right value:

`{ "status": "ok", "try_number": "15" }`